# How to get the top, left position of an Image relative to the entire screen in react native

Tags: css, react-native

How do I get the top and left position of a react native Image relative to the entire screen?

For example, I'm using pan responder that only allows me to keep track of the position of my finger. The "touch" area is this square box and there's a small image within the square box. If the finger touches any part of that box, a small image within the box moves along with the finger and then follow along with it. However, on touch, I want the small image to be right on top of my finger. How do I do that?

Comment: Please share your code and have a read  of [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sharing your code would allow us to help you more effectively. You may not even need to know image position on screen to achieve what you're looking for, for an example, but without your code I cant verify

Comment: If you need to get the image position on then `onLayout` or `measure` will allow you store this in a state object

Comment: However, while playing around with panhandler I noticed that the discrepancy between the cursor and my view was because the panhandler's x and y coordinates were the top left corner  of the view rather than the center. Simply subtracting half the view's height and width from the panhandler's x/y placed centered the view on the cursor, making the view appear on top of the cursor